# How to always add http protocol on links with php?

Tags: php

I have a function to create html links from text in php.
I'd like to always add http:// before links.

```
function toLink($titulo){
    $url = '~(?:(https?)://([^\s<]+)|(www\.[^\s<]+?\.[^\s<]+))(?<![\.,:])~i'; 
    $titulo = preg_replace($url, '<a href="$0" target="_blank" title="$0">$0</a>', $titulo);
    return $titulo;
}
```

and:

```
$titulo = toLink("some text: www.example.com");
```

I'd like this url to be convert to `<a href="http://www.example.com">` instead of `<a href="www.example.com">`.

In other words, I ALWAYS would like to have http on my links. If the text url has http or not. Any ideas how to always have http at the begining of the url?

thanks.

Comment: Your RegExp is explicitly stripping the protocol ... why?

Comment: @CD001 I don't know, I get this regex in another topic.

Comment: Well - it's not explicitly stripping it, it's just format matching and happily accepting it with or without the protocol - it's not really designed for what you're attempting.

Comment: @CD001 any ideas how to transform text links into links with http at the beggining?

Comment: I might consider using [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and checking to see if the protocol is there and, if not, prefixing it ... though you'd need to know whether the destination was supposed to be `http` or `https`